# Local maximum and level curves on a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This was an exam question I found and I need some help figuring it out

A village is founded in a mountain area of which the height (in meters) is calculated by
$$H(x,y)=500e^{-(x-2)^2-(y-x)^2}$$
a) Check if $H$ has a local maximum. Is this the global maximum? Where is this achieved and what is the height?

b) The centre of the village is found at point $(0,0)$. From there a road goes around the village at a constant height. On which point does it have the highest $y$-value and on which the lowest?

For a) I started with normal techniques to calculate the local max and found $(2,2)$ to be it. But i'm not quite sure how to get b).

Comment: There is a global maximum at $$(2,2)$$

Comment: Hint: the height depends only on $(x-2)^2 + (y-x)^2$.  At $(0,0)$ this is $4$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Aha so I don't have to look at the rest anymore? And to answer b I would just have to calculate the maximum and minimum of that function?

Comment: The maximum and minimum of $y$ subject to $(x-2)^2 + (y-x)^2 = 4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

The equation of whole the village would be$$e^{-4}=e^{-(x-2)^2-(x-y)^2}$$therefore $$(x-2)^2+(x-y)^2=4$$By defining $$x-2=2\cos\theta\\y-x=2\sin \theta$$we obtain $$x=2+2\cos\theta\\y=2+2\sin \theta+2\cos\theta$$from which the maximum and minimum could be easily found.

Comment: Thank you very much! So to find the highest y-value I just have to derive the y = 2 + 2sin + 2cos, find stationary points and do second derivate test?

Comment: You're welcome. That's right. After finding $\theta$ substitute it in $x$ to find the full coordinates....